# mysql - finding last service id

Tags: mysql

I have a database with 4 tables: company, tmid, service, provider.
Below image is the record:
[image]

My requirement is the following:
(1) last service ID 
(2) pID = 2
(3) default = Y

I tried the below query and cannot get my expected output:

```
(1)
select c.cID, max(s.svcID) as svcID, s.svcNote, s.svcStatus, tm.idm, tm.idt, p.pName
from service s
left join tmid tm on s.sNo = tm.sNo
left join provider p on tm.pID = p.pID
left join company c on s.cID = c.cID
where tm.default = 'Y' && tm.pID = 2
group by c.cID
order by c.cJoinDate desc

(2)
select c.cID, max(s.svcID) as svcID, s.svcNote, s.svcStatus, tm.idm, tm.idt, p.pName
from service s
left join tmid tm on s.sNo = tm.sNo
left join provider p on tm.pID = p.pID
left join company c on s.cID = c.cID
where tm.default = 'Y' && tm.pID = 2
group by c.cID, s.svcID
order by c.cJoinDate desc
```

My expected output is like the below image:
[image]

Can someone help me?

Comment: Can you post the create statements for all of your tables/test data?

Comment: If you expect that output, why you put `s.svcID = 2` in your WHERE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need a query like this:

```
select s.svcid, s.svcstatus, svcnote, t.idm, t.idt, p.pname
from service s
inner join tmid t on s.sno = t.sno and 'Y' = t.dft
inner join provider p on t.pid = p.pid
where s.pid = 2

union all

select s.svcid, s.svcstatus, svcnote, t.idm, t.idt, p.pname
from service s
inner join tmid t on s.sno = t.sno and 'Y' = t.dft
inner join provider p on t.pid = p.pid
where s.svcid = (select max(svcid) from service);
```

Example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8ef422/1

Create statements:

```
create table service (
  svcID int,
  svcStatus varchar(20),
  sNo int,
  cID int,
  svcNote varchar(20),
  pID int
);
insert into service values
(1, 'CLOSED', 111111, 1, 'service note 1', null),
(2, 'OPEN', 111111, 1, 'service note 2', 2),
(3, 'CLOSED', 111112, 2, 'service note 3', null),
(4, 'OPEN', 111112, 2, 'service note 4', 2),
(5, 'CLOSED', 111113, 3, 'service note 5', null);

create table tmid (
  ID int,
  sNo int,
  idm varchar(20),
  idt varchar(20),
  pID int,
  dft char(10)
);
insert into tmid values
(1, 111111, 'test00001', 'test00001', 1, 'N'),
(2, 111111, 'test00002', 'test00002', 2, 'Y'),
(3, 111111, 'test00003', 'test00003', 1, 'N'),
(4, 111112, 'test00004', 'test00004', 2, 'Y'),
(5, 111112, 'test00005', 'test00005', 3, 'N'),
(6, 111113, 'test00006', 'test00006', 2, 'Y'),
(7, 111113, 'test00007', 'test00007', 1, 'N');

create table provider (pid int, pname varchar(20));
insert into provider values (1, 'Maybank'), (2, 'Public Bank'), (3, 'CIMB Bank');
```

Result:

```
| svcid | svcstatus |        svcnote |       idm |       idt |       pname |
|-------|-----------|----------------|-----------|-----------|-------------|
|     2 |      OPEN | service note 2 | test00002 | test00002 | Public Bank |
|     4 |      OPEN | service note 4 | test00004 | test00004 | Public Bank |
|     5 |    CLOSED | service note 5 | test00006 | test00006 | Public Bank |
```

EDIT:

Based on your updated query and my better understanding of your needs, you could write a query like this:

```
select s.svcid, s.svcstatus, s.svcnote, t.idm, t.idt, p.pname
from tmid t
inner join provider p on t.pid = p.pid
inner join (select sno, max(svcid) maxsvcid from service group by sno) x
  on t.sno = x.sno
inner join service s on x.sno = s.sno and x.maxsvcid = s.svcid
where t.dft = 'Y' and t.pid = 2
```

Example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bd2a13/5

Result:

```
| svcID | svcStatus |        svcNote |       idm |       idt |       pname |
|-------|-----------|----------------|-----------|-----------|-------------|
|     2 |      OPEN | service note 2 | test00002 | test00002 | Public Bank |
|     4 |      OPEN | service note 4 | test00004 | test00004 | Public Bank |
|     5 |    CLOSED | service note 5 | test00006 | test00006 | Public Bank |
```

Comment: I really love your create statements... And I have edited my query, can you please have a look and modify the query in order to get my expected output?

Comment: Sure, I understood your requirements better and edited my answer with a query that will work nicely for you.

Comment: Does my edit help you? If it does, please feel free to put closure to your question by accepting it. If it does not help, let me know how I can assist

Comment: I need your assists... Can you please go to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34439005/mysql-show-2-seperate-provider-name-from-1-provider-table and have a look?

Comment: I've added an answer there